# Laravel Is it possible to improve Auth::id() query?

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-authorization

On Laravel, running any `Auth` function to retrieve the authenticated user `Auth::user()`, `Auth::check()` or `Auth::id()`, always generates the following query:

```
select * from `users` where `id` = 1 limit 1
```

This, in many cases could be more efficient since I just wanted to know if the user is authenticated.

By using `Auth::id()` the query should be at least optimized to `select id from`, instead of `select * from`.

Is there a way to avoid the query to be run or at least improve it?

Comment: `COUNT(*)` is faster than `COUNT(id)` may be this is similar concept. I do not know, just a thought.

Comment: Use [sessions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/session) to store user data.

Comment: @vivek_23 session is an option, but I would prefer to rely on Laravel proper Authentication methods.

Comment: Are you sure it is using 'select * from `users` where `id` = 1 limit 1' query on call of Auth::id(); I doubt it is hitting to db all time, it will be picking data from any other means

Comment: Can you explain your problem with the given query? If a session is used to store the ID, how could the ID get in there if it was not already present in the database - so a `COUNT` would always return 1, such that you could completely avoid that query

Comment: why not create your own helper `isUserAthenticated()` using the custom query

Comment: I want to avoid accessing the database to check if user is authenticated. Because, on my navbar I need to place a logout button in case the user is authenticated, to do that, Laravel always query the database to retrieve the user object, even though I'm not going to use any information about the user. Is there any way to get it from session?

Comment: @ToniAlmeida Did you find a proper solution to it? if yes, please post it as solution.

Answer (score 1):

What I found is the definition of `Auth::id()` / `auth()->id()` is

```
public function id()
{
    if ($this->loggedOut) {
        return;
    }

    return $this->user()
                ? $this->user()->getAuthIdentifier()
                : $this->session->get($this->getName());
}
```

It means it is already using session.

Now for better way to get this done, may be you need to look more into `SessionGuard`and `Auth` contracts.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Prafulla can you tell me what class is that? Maybe that `$this->loggedOut` is all I need, to avoid querying the database.

Comment: @ToniAlmeida SessionGuard is the class. That is in Illuminate\Auth namespace.

Comment: @ToniAlmeida Do you got a better solution? Can you share your solution here?

Comment: I haven't, as far as I understand Laravel will always check if the authenticated user is in the database (the user may have been deleted meanwhile). And by checking, will always return full user data.
In my case I just wanted the ID, it's a waste of resources to retrieve everything (`select *`). It would be better to have a simple method to return id only.

Comment: @ToniAlmeida you are correct, do you think it is possible by any means?